# Why context help shows content of _ide_helper_models.php file?

Tags: phpstorm

In my  PhpStorm 2023.2.2 context help periodically shows content of
_ide_helper_models.php file :

[image]

I fill this file in settings :
[image]

But that does not work and I see context help  just as in 1st printscreen...
Some other options ?

Comment: You are not supposed to exclude the helper files - otherwise, you won't have proper completion and analysis, as PhpStorm can't learn the Laravel magic by just looking at the Laravel sources. Why is this inspection warning an issue for you? You can just disable the inspection if it's bothering you

Comment: Where I can  disable the inspection ?

Comment: You can disable it at *Settings | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Undefined symbols | Multiple class declarations*.
In general, you can disable any inspection [through the Alt+Enter menu](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#disable_in_editor)